# Google Chart Tools truncating y axis labels

Tags: google-visualization, truncated, axis-labels

Working with a [Google bar chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart.html), here is what I got:

[image]

Here my custom options

```
var options = {
    width: 500, height: 240,
    legend : 'none',
    vAxis:{title:'Answers',textStyle:{color: '#005500',fontSize: '12', paddingRight: '100',marginRight: '100'}},
    hAxis: { title: 'Percentage', textStyle: { color: '#005500', fontSize: '12', paddingRight: '100', marginRight: '100'} } 
 };
```

Can't I set a width for these `<g>` / `<rect>` tags?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe the chartArea.left option is what you are looking for. Try something like this, and mess around with chartArea.left and chartArea.width values (should add up to your total width of 500 though) until your y labels are all visible:

```
var options = {
    width: 500, height: 240,
    legend : 'none',
    vAxis:{title:'Answers',textStyle:{color: '#005500',fontSize: '12', paddingRight: '100',marginRight: '100'}},
    hAxis: { title: 'Percentage', textStyle: { color: '#005500', fontSize: '12', paddingRight: '100', marginRight: '100'} },
    chartArea: {left:100, width: 400} 
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

chartArea width can be set in percentage. chartArea: {width: 50%}. This will leave up to 50% of the total chart width to the left column.