# how to display all percentages on Google PieChart

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm facing two problems.

- How can I make sure that the whole legend can be seen under the graph? Indeed when the legend is too big three points are added.
- My other problem concerns pie charts. How to make all the percentages appear on the graph, by default it puts them only when the place is sufficient on the graph?

[Bar Chart problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqVee.png)
[Pie Chart problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYoKE.png)

Thanks you

Comment: It would be more helpful if you share your implementation so we can get a clear picture.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without changing the chart size.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, please check this before you post a question: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I put two images to illustrate my problem

Comment: Still could't get the Bar Chart problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bar Chart Problem :** Its the default behaviour. The 3-dots is called `ellipses`. It is used to truncate the strings to fit the in to the containing box/div. For more info, [refer this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/). [This workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899132/google-chart-tools-truncating-y-axis-labels) would help you if you wish the axes labels are need to be shown full. In case legend values, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980002/how-to-prevent-legend-labels-being-cut-off-in-google-charts).

> Please refrain rom using such long names for the axes as it affects the UX.

**Pie Chart Problem :** Its the default behaviour of Google Charts to show the values only if the values are sufficient to fit in the place. As a workaround, you can display all the values, in the chart using the option `{legend : "labelled"}`. Thanks to this [Google Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/uzRKrU7-PHs).

[Example JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rd751hx/8/)

Comment: Do you have any idea about my other problem ?

Comment: No. I still couldn't get what you are trying to tell about the first !

Comment: If there is a large string of characters, the graph cuts it automatically. For example on the image I inserted, you can see three dots after the q because the string must contain too many? the character chain for this example is in fact : qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq.
I hope it's clearer.